# How to Configure Inlay Hints in Rust Analyzer with Neovim Using nvim-cmp and nvim-lspconfig

Tags: neovim, rust-analyzer, nvim-lspconfig, nvim.cmp

I'm setting up a Rust development environment in Neovim and am looking to enable inlay hints using `rust-analyzer`. My setup includes `nvim-cmp` and `nvim-lspconfig`, but I'm not interested in using `rust-tools.nvim` or `mrcjkb/rustaceanvim`.

My current configuration for `rust-analyzer` in Neovim is as follows:

```lua
require('lspconfig').rust_analyzer.setup({
    on_attach=on_attach,
    settings = {
        ["rust-analyzer"] = {
            imports = {
                granularity = {
                    group = "module",
                },
                prefix = "self",
            },
            cargo = {
                buildScripts = {
                    enable = true,
                },
            },
            procMacro = {
                enable = true
            },
        }
    }
})
```

Despite this setup, I am unable to get inlay hints to display. The rest of the `rust-analyzer` features, such as code jumping, are working perfectly. Could anyone provide guidance on how to correctly enable inlay hints with this configuration, or suggest what might be missing or incorrect?

Comment: Do you use neovim dev version 0.10 ? Inlay hints are supported only in the dev version (not in current version 0.9.4). See this PR https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/23984

Comment: I'm currently use 0.9.5. I can't use inlay type hint in this version ? And I can see inlay type hit using rust-tools.nvim.

Comment: Is there any way to show inlay type hint in neovim?

Comment: Inlay hints are only supported with Neovim version >= 0.10 (current dev version). rust-tools.nvim plugin (dev discontinued) adds its own implementation of Inlay hints for Neovim 0.9 => https://github.com/simrat39/rust-tools.nvim